# Setting up Doctrine_Collection key mapping attribute in schema.yml

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2, schema.yml

In Doctrine 1.2, it is possible to set up [Key Mapping](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/component-overview/en#collection:key-mapping) for a table where `Doctrine_Collection` objects created by that table will populate keys from a particular column in each record in the collection.

An example from the documentation linked above:

> You may want to map the name column:
>
> ```
> // test.php
>
> // ...
> $userTable = Doctrine_Core::getTable('User');
>
> $userTable->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_COLL_KEY, 'username');
> ```
>
> Now user collections will use the values of name column as element indexes:
>
> ```
> // test.php
>
> // ...
> $users = $userTable->findAll();
>
> foreach($users as $username => $user) {
>     echo $username . ' - ' . $user->created_at . "\n";
> }
> ```

Is there a way to set this up in a schema.yml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While exploring a similar issue, I came across [this example](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/pl/yaml-schema-files#relationships%3amany-to-many):

> ```
> ---
> User:
>   columns:
>     ...
>   attributes:
>     export: all
>     validate: true
> ```

Applying the same principle with the `coll_key` attribute yields this:

```
User:
  columns:
    ...
  attributes:
    coll_key: username
```

We can verify after doing a build that the attribute was accepted:

```
$this->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_COLL_KEY, 'username');
```

---

There is one caveat, though.  You have to explicitly create the column that you want to use, or else Doctrine will throw an error during the build process:

```
User:
  actAs:
    Sluggable:  ~
  columns:
    ...
  attributes:
    coll_key:  slug
```

```
$ symfony doctrine:build --all --no-confirmation
>> doctrine  Dropping "doctrine" database
>> doctrine  Creating "dev" environment "doctrine" database
>> doctrine  generating model classes
>> file+     /tmp/doctrine_schema_60681.yml
   ...
>> doctrine  generating form classes

  Couldn't set collection key attribute. No such field 'slug'.
```

To get the above to work, you would need to explicitly specify the `slug` column, even though the `Sluggable` template normally creates it for you automatically:

```
User:
  actAs:
    Sluggable:  ~
  columns:
    ...
    slug:
      type:    string(50)
      unique:  true
  attributes:
    coll_key:  slug
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, it is not well documented.
You can specify options for a table in the table definition, [like this](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/pl/yaml-schema-files#features-examples%3aoptions)
Knowing that

```
const ATTR_COLL_KEY             = 108;
```

I would try :

```
User:
  options:
    attr_coll_key: username
```

then

```
User:
  options:
    attrCollKey: username
```

or even

```
User:
  options:
    108: username
```

I couldn't find precisely where in the code the options are handled, but you could do this with xdebug step-by-step debugging.

Good luck, and tell use if one of these tries works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; they were an excellent starting point!  I was able to get it working by specifying it as an attribute rather than an option (see my answer for more info).

Comment: @Phoenix: didn't event know you could set attributes in the schema, great job!